# Rank of a hollow matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

$A$ is a $d \times d$ square and symmetric matrix.

$A(i,i)=0$ for all $i$,

$A(i,j)>0$ and *distinct* for $i \neq j$.

Is $A$ full-rank, or invertible? This is true for $d=2,3,4$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determinant of symmetric matrix with the main diagonal elements zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144148/determinant-of-symmetric-matrix-with-the-main-diagonal-elements-zero)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the matrix is symmetric, $a_{i,j} = a_{j,i}$, so they can't all be distinct for $i \ne j$ (if $n \ge 2$).  I assume you mean distinct for $i > j$.

In the $4 \times 4$ case,  $\det(A)=0$ if
$$ a_{1,2} = {\frac {a_{{1,3}}a_{{2,4}}+a_{{1,4}}a_{{2,3}}+2\,\sqrt {a_{{1,3}}a_{{1
,4}}a_{{2,3}}a_{{2,4}}}}{a_{{3,4}}}}
$$
For example, try
$$ \pmatrix{0 & t & 1 & 2\cr t & 0 & 3 & 4\cr 1 & 3 & 0 & 5\cr 2 & 4 & 5 & 0\cr}$$
where $t = 2 + 4 \sqrt{6}/5$.

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample!

Answer (score 1):

A counterexample is given as follows:

\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 2 & 3 & 15 \\
2 & 0 & 5 & 9 \\
3 & 5 & 0 & 6 \\
15 & 9 & 6 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}

This matrix has determinant zero.

Reference: [Determinant of symmetric matrix with the main diagonal elements zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144148/determinant-of-symmetric-matrix-with-the-main-diagonal-elements-zero)