# $\text{det}(\text{abs}({\bf d - d}^T))$ being zero implies two or more elements equal in $\bf d$?

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question, determinant, matrix-rank, computational-mathematics

When implementing a clustering algorithm earlier today I investigated (in Matlab syntax):

$$\text{det}(\text{abs}({\bf d - d}^T)), {\bf d }\in \mathbb R^{N}$$

**edit:** In non-Matlab syntax: $$\text{det}(\text{abs}({\bf d1}^T-{\bf 1d}^T))$$

In other words the determinant of a matrix consisting of absolute value of pairwise differences.

Now since determinants are usually terrible to calculate, this is mostly of a curiosity of mine, but it seems that if any two elements of $\bf d$ are the same, then the above determinant is 0, and if no two elements of $\bf d$ are the same, then determinant $\neq 0$.

Can we prove this?

For example the vector ${\bf d} =  [1,2,3]^T$:

$$\text{det}(\text{abs}({\bf d - d}^T)) = \begin{bmatrix}|1-1|&|1-2|&|1-3|\\|2-1|&|2-2|&|2-3|\\|3-1|&|3-2|&|3-3|\end{bmatrix} = \left\|\begin{bmatrix}0&1&2\\1&0&1\\2&1&0\end{bmatrix}\right\|\neq 0$$
And the vector : ${\bf d} = [3,2,3]^T$:
$$\text{det}(\text{abs}({\bf d - d}^T)) = \begin{bmatrix}|3-3|&|3-2|&|3-3|\\|2-3|&|2-2|&|3-3|\\|3-3|&|3-2|&|3-3|\end{bmatrix} = \left\|\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\1&0&1\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}\right\|= 0$$

Comment: I think your notation is confusing here, because if $\mathbf{d}$ is a vector, then $\mathbf{d}-\mathbf{d}^T$ isn't well-defined; one is an $n\times1$ matrix while the other is a $1\times n$ matrix.

Comment: Yes, it is true. Write $d=[a,b,c]$ and consider your matrix. It has two parallel columns if two elements are the same.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki yes it is a bit confusing, which is why I wrote "Matlab syntax". I will try and find a better way to write it. ${\bf 1 d}^T - {\bf d 1}^T$ should be more understandable, I suppose?

Comment: @mathreadler That works; another would be to use $\otimes$ for the (implicit) tensor product there: $\mathbf{1\otimes d}-\mathbf{d\otimes 1}$.

Comment: Even with the products cleared up, I suggest restraint about using $\left|\cdot\right|$ for the entrywise absolute value of a matrix... Also, I'd say explicitly that the $d_i$ are real numbers, if you mean them to be.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is true. By permuting the rows and columns of the matrix, we may assume that the entries of $\mathbf d=(d_1,d_2,\ldots,d_n)^T$ are arranged in descending order. Moreover, since the rows and columns are simultaneously permuted, the determinant is unchanged. Now let $\Delta_i=d_i-d_{i+1}$,
$$
L=\pmatrix{1\\ &\ddots\\ &&\ddots\\ &&&1\\ \frac12&\frac12&\cdots&\frac12&1}
\ \text{ and }
\ U=\pmatrix{1&-1\\ &\ddots&\ddots\\ &&\ddots&\ddots\\ &&&\ddots&-1\\ &&&&1}.
$$
Then
\begin{aligned}
A:=|\mathbf d\mathbf 1^T-\mathbf 1\mathbf d^T|
&=\pmatrix{0&d_1-d_2&d_1-d_3&\cdots&d_1-d_n\\
d_1-d_2&0&d_2-d_3&\cdots&d_2-d_n\\
d_1-d_3&d_2-d_3&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&0&d_{n-1}-d_n\\
d_1-d_n&d_2-d_n&\cdots&d_{n-1}-d_n&0},\\
B:=UAU^T
&=\pmatrix{-2\Delta_1&0&\cdots&0&\Delta_1\\
0&-2\Delta_2&\ddots&\vdots&\Delta_2\\
\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&0&\vdots\\
0&\cdots&0&-2\Delta_{n-1}&\Delta_{n-1}\\
\Delta_1&\Delta_2&\cdots&\Delta_{n-1}&0},\\
C:=LBL^T
&=\pmatrix{-2\Delta_1&0&\cdots&0&0\\
0&-2\Delta_2&\ddots&\vdots&0\\
\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&0&\vdots\\
0&\cdots&0&-2\Delta_{n-1}&0\\
0&0&\cdots&0&\frac12(d_1-d_n)}.
\end{aligned}
Since $U$ and $L$ have determinants $1$,
\begin{aligned}
\det A=\det C
&=\left[\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}(-2\Delta_i)\right]\left[\frac12(d_1-d_n)\right]\\
&=\left[\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}(-2\Delta_i)\right]\left[-\frac12(d_n-d_1)\right]\\
&=(-2)^{n-2}\prod_{cyc}(d_i-d_{i+1}).
\end{aligned}
(If the $d_i$s are arranged in *ascending* order, the formula becomes $\det A=2^{n-2}\prod_{cyc}(d_i-d_{i+1})$ instead.) Hence $A$ is nonsingular if and only if all entries of $\mathbf d$ are distinct.

---

**Remark.** As pointed out by darij grinberg, there is actually a more general result, namely, if $\mathbf x_1,\ldots,\mathbf x_n\in\mathbb R^m$ and $A$ is the distance matrix defined by $a_{ij}=\|\mathbf x_i-\mathbf x_j\|_2$, then:

1. (cf. [A matrix involving distances of $n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3001258) ) $A$ is negative semidefinite on $\mathbf1^\perp$ and if all $\mathbf x_i$s are distinct, it is negative definite on $\mathbf1^\perp$;
2. (cf. [Nonsingularity of Euclidean distance matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/186830) ) when all $\mathbf x_i$s are distinct, since we also have $\mathbf1^TA\mathbf1>0$, $A$ must be nonsingular.

My argument above only proves the non-singularity of $A$ when $m=1$. It cannot deal with the higher-dimensional case and it doesn't concern about the negative semidefiniteness of $A$ on $\mathbf1^\perp$.

Comment: Cool! Thank you.

Comment: Oh nice! I figured a cyclic product might be the result but I'd missed the notion of sorting $\mathbf{d}$ in increasing order as a way of ensuring specific signs on the absolute values, and so my result didn't satisfy the requirement of being zero if any two $d_i$ were equal.  Very slick!

Comment: Now try the case when $d_1, d_2, \ldots, d_n$ are complex numbers, or more generally, vectors in a Euclidean space :) (No guarantee the claim is true in this case, but your argument definitely doesn't work.)

Comment: Ah: The claim is indeed true when $d_1, d_2, \ldots, d_n$ are vectors in any Euclidean space. This is proved in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186830/nonsingularity-of-euclidean-distance-matrix/3010694#3010694 .

Answer (score 3):

The second half — the assertion that if two elements are the same, then the determinant is zero — is trivial; if two elements are the same then their vector of (absolute values of) pairwise differences with all elements will be the same, and so your matrix will have two identical columns.

Comment: Ah of course! How simple! That automatically reduces rank by 1 which ensures one 0 eigenvalue and det 0.

Comment: @mathreadler That said, the first half seems non-trivial, and I'm still curious myself as to what the answer is there and what that determinant might represent, if anything.

Comment: First half you mean if it never is 0 if no two are the same?

Comment: @mathreadler If $d=[a,b,c]$ then the determinant is $2|a-b||a-c||b-c|$, which makes the converse trivial as well (for $3\times 3$ matrix).

Comment: @A.Γ. Nice! That cleanly solves the 3x3 case. Do you know if there's something similar for the general case?

Comment: @A.Γ. maybe we can use it as base case for induction?

Comment: @mathreadler [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144148/determinant-of-symmetric-matrix-with-the-main-diagonal-elements-zero). Can we make a counterexample of that? (I am not sure, 4 unknowns, 6 equations, but maybe some variation would work).

Comment: @A.Γ. yep, thanks!